# Autofit columns starting with a specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

below is the formula I want to use.  I'm just not sure how to add the command to start from a specific worksheet.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
sh.Columns.AutoFit
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Check out https://trumpexcel.com/vba-worksheets/#Referencing-a-Worksheet-in-VBA for how to reference a specific worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use an Index instead:

```
Dim nIndex As Integer
For nIndex = 1 To ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets.Count
  ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets(nIndex).Columns.AutoFit
Next
```

Change the `1` to whichever one you want to start with.

Or you could check the name of the worksheet in the loop instead, and process all of them after and including that one:

```
Dim bFlag As Boolean ' default value is False
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If sh.Name = "First One" Then bFlag = True
  ' once the flag is set to True, it stays True til the end
  If bFlag Then sh.Columns.AutoFit
Next
```

Comment: thank you so much! the first option worked! appreciate your help so much!